# How long before an s3 bucket can be created with same name after deletion?

Tags: amazon-s3, provisioning

Title is quite explanatory, but I have just deleted an s3 bucket as it was in the wrong region and am wanting to recreate it in the correct region with same name as the just deleted one.

Is there any documentation of this or user experience?

Comment: Delete bucket `A` in region `1` and recreating it in region `2`, I've had to wait as long as 45-minutes.

Comment: Many hours in my experience. You can recreate it in the console almost instantly, but the bucket is not really there. It doesn't show any access or region information and gives an error when listing the content. Same result with the CLI. My guess is that amazon runs some process every few hours that performs the needed cleanup.

Comment: "You can recreate it in the console almost instantly" -- that does not match my experience. Instead, it throws an API error like so: "A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again." (That was via the AWS Console, not using the CLI or one of the SDKs, I'll note.)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html) used to say:

> When you delete a bucket, there may be a delay of up to one hour before the bucket name is available for reuse in a new region or by a new bucket owner. If you re-create the bucket in the same region or with the same bucket owner, there is no delay.

But now they just say:

> ... it might take some time before the name can be reused ...

Comment: This information may be out of date as it's been removed from the documentation.

Comment: Today it took more than 1h for me.

Comment: This seems to also apply for moving buckets from one AWS account to another.

Comment: If you delete a bucket and recreate it in the same region and account, it's a few seconds in general. The long wait times happen if you switch account when recreating, and maybe if you switch region in the same account. Haven't tried the latter.

Comment: I'm trying to 'move' a bucket from one region to another on the same account and getting the error `A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.`. I'll update how long it takes once complete.

Comment: It took me 1 hour 45 mins today.

Comment: @DeanMeehan how long did it take? Or are you still waiting?

Comment: @Ian It was aprox. the same as above. 1hr 45minutes. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: It took me about an hour. Specifically, trying to create the bucket while creating a CloudFormation stack led to get the "conflicting conditional operation" error after half an hour on the first try and took another half an hour to succeed on the second try.

Answer (score 18):

I've had to wait 5-10 minutes at times.

Comment: It's been over half an hour and I'm still waiting...

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi OK? Contact AWS support if it's still stuck.

Comment: It took over an hour. Just letting people know not to pin their hopes on it taking 10 minutes, it may take much longer.

Comment: Took exactly an hour today.

Comment: FYI, deleted three buckets because I wanted to move them to a different region. It took an hour for one of the names to become available after deletion. However, it took several hours for two of them to become available (they were in a sort of limbo: still showing in the list after deletion, but without region name and without any ability to try and delete them again.) So bottom-line: just be patient.

Comment: yeah, bucket limbo state, having same issue, sometimes its super fast, today its already 12 hours...

Comment: Took about an hour for one bucket, and even more for another.

Answer (score -8):

about 5-10 seconds. <s>Bucket names must be region-unique (you can create us-1/test and eu-1/test simultaneously)</s>. It looks like someone create bucket in region with name you want to use.

edit: Bucket name is globally unique.

Comment: was able to create it, but more inline with the 5 to 10mins below. The string was very unique, so was not created by anyone else.

Comment: This answer provides additional information that is not at all accurate.  Bucket names are a single global (not regional) namespace. [*"The bucket namespace is global - just like domain names. You can't create a bucket with a name that is already used by another Amazon S3 user."*](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-S3/1109#02)  You also can't create one with the same name as one you already have in a different region.

Comment: "The string was very unique" - it's a binary property 